# Visual Basic with Oracle: need Provider OLE DB for Oracle

Tags: vb.net, oracle

How can I add Microsoft Provider OLE DB for Oracle. I had Microsoft ODBC for Oracle, but I want to add a provider mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly,

http://www.connectionstrings.com/

will usually help you.

You need (if I remember correctly) OraOLEDB.

Answer (score 0):

> Microsoft Provider oledb for Oracle

Means that the connection string will be

```
Provider=msdaora;Data Source=MyOracleDB;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Replace Data Source, user name and password as per your configuration.